# Суффикс -j-.

Tags: суффиксы, морфемика

Здравствуйте, господа товарищи. Помогите, бога ради, малограмотным слоям населения. А именно: скажите, в словах вроде делегаци[й - а], авиаци[й - а] суффикс -аций или два суффикса -  -аци- и -й-. Ведь при изменении этих слов -й- куда-то пропадает: авиаци[й - а] - ави-аци-онн-ый,  делегаци[й - а] - делег-аци-онн-ый. Суффикс -й- выпадает или происходит чередование -аций-/-аци-? 
И еще один вопрос. В словах лили[й - а], арми[й - а] суффикс -й- и -ий- соответственно. Что происходит с этими суффиксами в форме предложного падежа (лилии, армии)?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: инкогнито и  анонимусу, которые малограмотные и "академиев" не кончали, может ответить только tmt. И плюсик получить.

Comment: Не понял, зачем кто-то добавил минус. Добавил из чувства справедливости плюс. Вопрос, ну... вполне может возникнуть у думающего человека.

Comment: Спасибо, очень обстоятельно все объяснили. Затрудняюсь выбрать лучший ответ.

Answer (score 5):

В словах делегация, авиация - суффикс, скорее, ци|j| (а буква *а* относится к корню). Усечение последней согласной **j** - достаточно типичное явление в русском словообразовании. Вот что говорит об этом *Русская грамматика* (§ 1062):

> Финаль |j| (без предшествующей беглой
> гласной), выступающая после согласной
> и **и** (фонемат. |и| и |a1|), отсутствует
> перед следующими морфами
> мотивированных слов: -ант: комедия –
> комедиант; -am: викарий – викариат,
> Азия – азиат; -анк(а): патриций –
> патрицианка; -тур(а): партия
> (оркестровая) – партитура; -етт(а):
> ария – ариетта; -альн-: премия –
> премиальный, гений – гениальный;
> -ельн-: платье – плательный; **-онн-: индукция – индукционный**; -ональн-:
> профессия – профессиональный; -озн-:
> религия – религиозный; -ан-: платье –
> платяной; -анск-: Венеция –
> венецианский, Конфуций –
> конфуцианский.

В формах *лилии*, *армии*, безусловно, есть звук (и фонема) **й** (пусть и в ослабленном варианте).

Comment: Увидел "делегировать". Значит, в "делегация" всё-таки корень *делег*, а суффикс в форме *аций*. И (вот засада!), подробнее изучив "авиа", нашёл "авиетку" и "авионику". Но всё равно считаю, что корень "авиа", а в словах "*авиа*етка", "*авиа*оника" гласная корня просто усекается (как бы усекается :-), в р.я.) перед след. гласной. Ну, не достаточно трёх букв (*ави*) для создания соотв. значения в русском языке!

Answer (score 3):

> делегаци[й - а], авиаци[й - а] суффикс -аций или два суффикса - -аци- и -й-

Вообще вопрос "один или два суффикса" - вопрос философский. Часто и так и эдак - правильно. Смотря по какой надобности этот разбор делается. В школе, например, множить без конкретной нужды суффиксы не принято, даже если это было бы правильно с исторической точки зрения. 
В данном же случае я особых причин для выделения отдельного суффикса Й (-j-) просто не вижу.

> Суффикс -й- выпадает или происходит чередование -аций-/-аци-? И еще один вопрос. В словах лили[й - а], арми[й - а] суффикс -й- и -ий- соответственно. Что происходит с этими суффиксами в форме предложного падежа (лилии, армии)? Заранее спасибо.

Если и чередование, то не морфемное, а чисто фонетическое, позиционное. В русском языке, в отличие, например, от украинского, сочетание ЙИ регулярно упрощается до И (или ИЙ - на слух это почти неразличимо). Таким образом чередования тут нет, просто в словах "лилии, армии, авиации" (формы множественного числа и родительного падежа) последняя И морфологически одновременно является и окончанием, и "спрятавшейся" частью суффикса. Для практики последний факт не столь важен, и поэтому обычно не упоминается вне специальных исследований.

Answer (score 2):

Ни в одном из названных слов нет суффикса -j- .   Этот скрытый суффикс есть в словах типа 
свин/ья -[св'ин'/ j /а].

Лили/я - скрытый j в корне,армия- то же самое по Потихе,по Зализняку: Корень: -арм-; суффикс: -иj-; окончание: -а.Куда девается в других падежах? - никуда не девается. Происходит слияние: j  в сочетании с И  на письме передается одной буквой и (хозяj + ин = хозя/ин, лилиj+ и = лили/я).При анализе морфемного разбора предлагается совместить  словообразовательный  и фонетический разборы.
 1)Учащиеся разбирают слово  как  обычно:  в/кле/ива/ть.  После
    того,  как  слово  разобрано,  учащиеся  делают  следующую  запись:   в-
    (приставка) + -клей- (корень) + -ива- (суффикс) + -ть (суфф. инф. или окончание).Лили/и= лилий[j}-корень, и-окончание.Лилей/ н /ый - чередов.и(ий)//ей
 2) Второй способ заключается в применении приема надписывания наверху после суфф. или корня частичную транскрипцию -[j]

авиа/ци/я = авиа+ци[j+а],делег/аци/я - то же самое :скрытый  j  в суффиксе, почему он усекается при образовании прилагательных? Потому что это в основном латинизмы, там твёрдое окончание -delegatus.Сохраняется твёрдость и суффикса при словообразовании от него в русском языке. Поначалу пытались говорить мягко: Шаг держи революциённый - это не привилось, осталось в просторечии.

Comment: А свинье точно суфикс -j-? Свин*ей*.

Comment: Нет, не точно, только по мнению тех, кто производит это слово от "свин",Зализняк считает, что это чередование в корне свин/свинь[j]. Точно суфф.j есть в кидают ( кид-а-j-ут),клоч-j-a, суч-j-a, друз-j-а,  колосья, листья и Поволжь/[й/-э],  счасть/-[й/-э], старь-[й/-о].

Comment: Ребята, кто знает, почему некоторое время назад я не могла добавить комментарий? Не открывается, и всё тут.

Comment: В этом вопросе? У меня было то же на соседнем форуме, Мете. Видимо, просто сбой временный.

Comment: Спасибо, а то я думала, что это только у меня, я что-то не то делаю.